# Enabling and disabling debugging on web.py

Tags: debugging, logging, web.py

I am trying to enable debugging on a web.py production server but unable to do so. Also, I am unable to do the reverse when running it locally.

http://webpy.org/tutorial3.en

It is mentioned on how to accomplish this at the bottom of the above but I am unsuccessful so far. I have tried the below.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    web.config.debug = False
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `web.config.debug = False` before creating the application.

```
import web

web.config.debug = True

urls = (
   ...
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```